# Invoking or compiling a directive from a filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, I wish to invoke certain directives whilst using a filter.

In this over simplified example, I have the a directive that responds to `<user></user>` tag.

I also have a filter that transforms an input into such tags, i.e

```
App.filter('addTags', [
  '$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(input) {
      (input.match(/@[A-Za-z0-9]+/) || []).forEach(function(tag) {
        input = input.replace(tag, '<user name="'+tag+'"></user>')
      });
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    };
  }
]);
```

How can I have this respond correctly to `<p ng-bind-html="text | addTags"></p>` making the `user` directive compile?

```
text = 'I call upon a @username'
```

should compile to `'I call upon a <user name="@username"></user>'`

Thanks

Comment: try to compile it using $sce.trustAsHtml($compile(input)($scope))     pass $scope as dependency in your filter

Comment: @Jugnu that results in multiple angular errors I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

After research, the correct solution to this issue would be changing "addTags" from a filter to a directive, in which we can recompile the output to call on other directives.

```
App.directive('addtags', ['$compile', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {ngModel: '='},
    template: '',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      var input = attrs.addtags;
      (input.match(/@[A-Za-z0-9]+/) || []).forEach(function(tag) {
         input = input.replace(tag, '<user name="'+tag+'"></user>')
      });
      elm.append(input);
      $compile(elm.contents())(scope);
    }
  }
}]
```

invoked upon as `<p addtags="{{text}}"></p>`